# Gradle maven-publish not updating metadata

Tags: gradle, maven-publish, maven-metadata

I have a very simple Gradle project which generates a jar file, and I am applying the maven-publish plugin and calling the `publish` task to publish artifacts to Artifactory:

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

**command**:

```
./gradlew :my-test-project:publish
```

This works fine and it publishes the artifact to Artifactory, however I see that the `latest` tag in the metadata xml is updated only intermittently:

**maven-metadata.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-test-project</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>0.0.3</latest>
    <release>0.0.7</release>
    <versions>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <version>0.0.3</version>
      <version>0.0.4</version>
      <version>0.0.5</version>
      <version>0.0.6</version>
      <version>0.0.7</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20181027171631</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Gradle version is 4.10.2. How can I ensure that the latest tag reflects the latest version? How is the publish plugin deciding that the current version is not latest? I am stuck on this.